# How I can doing a sum of a vector in $ℤ^{r}$ with a equivalence class in $ℤ/nℤ$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let us consider the following direct sum of groups:

$G=ℤ^{r}⊕ℤ/nℤ$

**My question** is: I know that every $w$ in $G$ can be written as: $w=u+v$ where $u$ is in $ℤ^{r}$ and $v$ is in $ℤ/nℤ$. However, I am not undestood how I can doing a sum of a vector in $ℤ^{r}$ with a equivalence class in $ℤ/nℤ$.

Comment: The direct sum you have written down is an *external* direct sum, whereas what you are used to think of is an internal direct sum. Once you learn about them and their differences/similarities, you'll understand why people usually leave off the external/internal and just say direct sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Purely formally.**

Among Abelian groups, finite direct sum is the same as (isomorphic to) direct product, so, we can also write
$$w=(u,v)\ \ \in \Bbb Z^r\times(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$$
if you prefer. Under the isomorphism $U\times V\to U\oplus V$, an element $(u,0)$ corresponds to $u\in U$ and $(0,v)$ to $v\in V$. Addition in $U\times V$ is given coordinatewise, so we have
$$(u,v)=(u,0)+(0,v)$$
which corresponds to $u+v$ whatever $+$ means in $U\otimes V$ (as long as the correspondence is isomorphism).

Comment: Dear Berci, I think the OP want to know deeply how tow vectors, one from $\mathbb Z^r$ and another from $\mathbb Z_n$ can be merged to give a new element. In fact, we want to know what is $$(a_1,a_2,...,a_r)+\bar{b}$$. Any way, +1

Comment: It's a *formal sum*, the $+$ in between can be considered as a separating character, and the written formal sum is then can be considered as the ordered pair $((a_1,a_2,...,a_r),\bar b)$.

Comment: Ok, @  Babak S and  Berci: Thank you very much for clarification.