# Can we extend the map $φ$ to $ℝ^{r}×C(ℚ)^{\text{tors}}→C(ℚ)$ as an isomorphism or not?

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

The motivation to this question can be found in

[How I can express $(x,y)∈G$ by using the $r$ independent points $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349922/how-i-can-express-x-yg-by-using-the-r-independent-points-p-1-p-2-ldots-p)

We know that there is an isomorphism  $$φ:ℤ^{r}×C(ℚ)^{\text{tors}}→ℤ^{r}⊕C(ℚ)^{\text{tors}}=C(ℚ)$$ defined by
$$(Q,T)→φ(Q,T)=Q+T$$

where $$Q=∑_{k=1}^{r}α_{k}P_{k}$$ and $T$ is a torsion point.

My **question** is: Can we extend the map $φ$ to $ℝ^{r}×C(ℚ)^{\text{tors}}→C(ℚ)$ as an isomorphism or not?

Comment: First of all, is there a bijection between these sets?

Comment: Yes, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346406/how-i-can-doing-a-sum-of-a-vector-in-r-with-a-equivalence-class-in-n

Comment: I don't see the connection between this question and the link. Here you have $\mathbb{R}^r$, which never appears there. Let me ask you this: is there a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In fact I do not know.

Comment: Well, the answer is no. There is a basic distinction between _countable_ sets (such as the natural numbers and integers) and _uncountable_ sets (such as the real numbers) that every student of math (no matter their interests) needs to be completely clear on. Wikipedia can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set

Comment: And what would $rP$ mean, when $r$ is a real number and $P$ is a point on $E$?

Comment: Yes. You are right, that element has no sense unless $r$ is an integer.